# DNS does not exist for domain - still able to connect to SSH

Tags: ssh, dns

A while ago I unsubscribed one domain name which I didn't use anymore, let's say abcd1234.com. It pointed to a server, and I used it to login to the server via SSH. I now use another domain name for this. A test via [Network-tools](http://network-tools.com/) shows that the domain is no longer active.

However - I just opened the terminal in Ubuntu, and accidentally typed in the old connection:

> ssh john@abcd1234.com

It asked me for my password, and I entered it. Then the login was refused, and after one more try I realised the mistake. Now I'm wondering what is happening here. So I did a test and did the same with abcd1234xxx.com. Then the following message followed:

> The authenticity of host 'abcd1234.com (0.0.0.0)' can't be established.

So either the domain name is known by the system, or it is active with SSH running. If I open the following file, I see hashes, no domain names, so there is nothing to search for.

> /home/john/.ssh/known_hosts

**What is happening here? Is this cache or how can you explain this? Can I remove these entries in the known hosts file?**

I changed my password to be sure.

Comment: type the word alias at the terminal prompt.  Did you set an alias to that address?  If so edit your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc and remove the alias to the address.

Comment: Maybe there is still some local dns cache where he resolves the address.

Comment: I never set an alias for a domain name in bash. Maybe I would do that for a command, but not for a domain name. I did check and it didn't show anything. Still a good tip though. Local dns cache seems more logical.

Comment: How long ago did you remove the DNS it can take up to 72 hours for changes to propagate.

Comment: I didn't login with this machine for maybe a month. The domain name was unsubscribed more than a month ago.

Answer (score 0):

Hey did you get your DNS working again.  Try this on command prompt to resolve unknown DNS issues: ipconfig /flushdns Good luck.